# Big Query seems to produce random sequenced results when given large ordered data sets

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am scanning 40GB ( 4 years ) of **partitioned** data. The partition is set on `rated_at`. The SQL call calculates the amount of time occurred between each record. For this to work, I'm using a SELF JOIN and a Sequence Number by using ROW_NUMBER().

However, when I run this code, I get `time_studied` for roughly ~11K records ( less than 1% of the total results ) in the negative.

A negative result should be impossible because they're all ordered by timestamp. As a negative result can only be derived from subtracting an newer time by an older time.

Every time I re-run this code, I get a different block of roughly 11K records, give or take a few hundred. If I were to run the same block of code but against any specific negative result, then the correct positive result is returned.

My theory is that due to BQ shuffling, it's losing the sequence number, and as a result its ordering.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    pack_id,
    DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(rated_at), "America/New_York") as rated_at,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY user_id, pack_id, rated_at) as seqnum
  FROM dp.table
  ORDER BY user_id, pack_id, rated_at
),

calculated_time AS (
  SELECT 
      t.user_id, 
      t.pack_id, 
      -- Here! We are clearly not _always_ using the actual tprev.rated_at
      sum( DATETIME_DIFF(t.rated_at, tprev.rated_at, SECOND) )
      ) as `time_studied`
  FROM cte t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cte tprev
    ON t.seqnum = tprev.seqnum + 1
  GROUP BY user_id, pack_id, t.rated_at
)

SELECT
  user_id,
  pack_id,
  SUM(time_studied) as time_studied,
FROM calculated_time
GROUP BY user_id, pack_id
```

Comment: You already seem to know window functions, as you're using `LAG() OVER()`. Instead of a self-join on a generated sequence number, why not an expression like: `DATETIME_DIFF(t.rated_at, LAG(t.rated) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id,pack_id ORDER BY rated_at)` (you're finally grouping by `user_id` and `pack_id`, after all, so the partitioning should be along the same criteria ...)

Comment: @marcothesane Would that account for this odd out-of-order issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would say: Welcome to MPP - Massive Parallel Processing!

If you don't explicitly add `ORDER BY` at the right place - or, at least, use the right partitioning and ordering clause, each node returns their rows at their own pace. And the query initiator node just passes the rows on as they come from the other nodes - in sort-of random order, if you don't `ORDER BY` at the top of the query.

Comment: Interesting. Would you know what top order I'm missing? I have it in the seqnumber, and the CTE.

Comment: I could also see this being because it is a partitioned table ( just added that very important bit to the description above )